# How to ensure updated files are served instead of cached ones?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I cache my CSS file and set their expiry date to a month from now. Suppose I have some updates and so modify the CSS file. How can I ensure that visitors to my website will be using the updated CSS instead of the old one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the name which would ensure that regardless of users browsers, they would get the new file. In all places you reference the CSS file, reference a variable containing the file name instead. When you release a new version, update the variable so all pages look at the new stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a query string to the url e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css?v1" />
```

Comment: Not all software will cache files with querystrings correctly. This is especially true for proxies.

Answer (score 2):

Change the URL. That will force browsers to re-download the file. The easiest thing is to have a number in the filename which you increment. Configure your web server with some rewrite rules so you won't need to rename the file every time.

This is my rewrite rule at [erefredag.se](http://erefredag.se/) for the Nginx server:

```
rewrite ^/style\..*\.css$ /style.css;
```

And this is what my `<link>` element looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.acf1a27de.css">
```